# If A1 and A2 = 0 Mark BOTH rows for deletion?

Tags: excel

So I am just wondering if this is possible and if so can someone point me in the right direction.

```
Steve   50
Steve  -50
Steve   50
Steve   35
Gregg   10
Gregg   10
Gregg   15
Jill    100
Jill   -17
Bob     200
Bob    -200
Bob     100
```

So what I would want do have the formula do is

```
Steve   50   Delete
Steve  -50   Delete
Steve   50
Steve   35
Gregg   10
Gregg   10
Gregg   15
Jill    100
Jill   -17
Bob     200  Delete
Bob    -200  Delete
Bob     100
```

I am open to any suggestions as well this is just the best way I can think to go at it with the data I have.

Comment: Do you have a title row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM inside and IF:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2=A3,SUM(B2:B3)=0),AND(A2=A1,SUM(B1:B2)=0,SIGN(B2)=-1)),"Delete","")
```

[image]

Comment: <Steve 50 
    Steve -50 
    Steve 50 It stops working here
    Gregg 10 
    Gregg 10 
    Gregg 15  
    Jill 100 
    Jill -17 
    Bob 200 Delete
    BoB -200 Delete>
Is there anyway around this? @scott

Comment: Are the numbers always grouped in twos? @SkysLastChance

Comment: Sometimes they will be grouped up to 5 times. @ScottCraner

Comment: @SkysLastChance you need to update the question with the other possible inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: @ScottCraner all udated, I have a feeling this is not possible

Comment: Have faith, does your actual data have a title row? @SkysLastChance

Comment: @ScottCraner I have hopes!, It has headers at the top yes.

Comment: @ScottCraner you are a god among men. Where do I even begin to learn something like this?

Comment: @SkysLastChance trial and error with a ever expanding knowledge of the logic of various functions.